# How to print breakpoint id in lldb

Tags: breakpoints, lldb

If I set an auto-continue breakpoint with a command how can I also print out the breakpoint id so I know which breakpoint is displaying the command.

In the list below I need to

> br command add "print brk-id" 27

But what is the command to do so, I'm not finding it in the docs or here on SO.

```
    Current breakpoints:
27: regex = 'coordinateReadingItemAtURL', module = Foundation, locations = 28, resolved = 28, hit count = 16 Options: enabled auto-continue
    Breakpoint commands:
      po $rdx

  27.1: where = Foundation`-[NSFileCoordinator coordinateReadingItemAtURL:options:error:byAccessor:], address = 0x00007fff534d2642, resolved, hit count = 3
  27.2: where = Foundation`-[NSFileCoordinator(NSPrivate) _coordinateReadingItemAtURL:options:error:byAccessor:], address = 0x00007fff534d2695, resolved, hit count = 3
  27.3: where = Foundation`__85-[NSFileCoordinator(NSPrivate) _coordinateReadingItemAtURL:options:error:byAccessor:]_block_invoke_2, address = 0x00007fff534d4d44, resolved, hit count = 2
  27.4: where = Foundation`__85-[NSFileCoordinator(NSPrivate) _coordinateReadingItemAtURL:options:error:byAccessor:]_block_invoke.404, address = 0x00007fff534d52bf, resolved, hit count = 2
  27.5: where = Foundation`__73-[NSFileCoordinator coordinateReadingItemAtURL:options:error:byAccessor:]_block_invoke, address = 0x00007fff534d5330, resolved, hit count = 2
  27.6: where = Foundation`__73-[NSFileCoordinator coordinateReadingItemAtURL:options:error:byAccessor:]_block_invoke_2, address = 0x00007fff534d5559, resolved, hit count = 2
  27.7: where = Foundation`__85-[NSFileCoordinator(NSPrivate) _coordinateReadingItemAtURL:options:error:byAccessor:]_block_invoke_2.405, address = 0x00007fff534d60e3, resolved, hit count = 2
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think there's a command that will print *only* the breakpoint id. The closest I know of is `thread info`:

```
br command add -o "thread info"
```

This will print a bunch of data, with the breakpoint id at the very end:

```
thread #1: tid = 0x2220c5, 0x000000010b6cc4dd SomeSDK`-[ABClass method:], queue = 'com.apple.main-thread', stop reason = breakpoint 1.1
```

This data is controlled by the `thread-format` setting. You could change the default to be more succinct, for example:

```
settings set thread-format "thread #${thread.index}{, stop reason = ${thread.stop-reason}}"
```

With this, `thread info` shows:

```
thread #1, stop reason = breakpoint 1.1
```

Keep in mind this setting is used in other places, and changes can show elsewhere.

Finally, you could resort to the Python API. This command will print the breakpoint id:

```
br command add -s python -o 'print "{}.{}".format(bp_loc.GetBreakpoint().GetID(), bp_loc.GetID())'
```

To explain this, Python breakpoint commands are actually a function, you can run `break list` to see how lldb will call it. One of the arguments is `bp_loc`, which is a `SBBreakpointLocation`. To get print the full breakpoint ID, this code combines the two ID values: `bp_loc.GetBreakpoint().GetID()` and `bp_loc.GetID()`.

For easy reuse, you could put this in a file somewhere, for example `helpers.py`.

```
# helpers.py
def brk_id(frame, bp_loc, internal_dict):
    bp_id = bp_loc.GetBreakpoint().GetID()
    loc_id = bp_loc.GetID()
    print "{}.{}".format(bp_id, loc_id)
```

Then in your `~/.lldbinit` you import it like so:

```
command script import path/to/helpers.py
```

And now you can use the helper function easily:

```
br command add -F helpers.brk_id
```